# Dynamically remove last string after / from string

Tags: unix

I have a string path like:

`/mnt/n011/ptm/trail/ela4local/ddlext/d1`

I need final string as:

`/mnt/n011/ptm/trail/ela4local/ddlext`

Basically anything after last / from path should be removed.
Need it through shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
foo="/mnt/n011/ptm/trail/ela4local/ddlext/d1" ;
echo "${foo%/*}"
output:
/mnt/n011/ptm/trail/ela4local/ddlext
```

Use

```
echo "${foo##*/}"
```

to get the string after last slash..

Take a look at this [question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111189)